# node.js mysql query update from an array

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am beginner in node.js , i hava an array of json data and i wanted to update my table squad by all the rows of my json array , so i used a loop , and then after i execute , i can only see the json input with console.log(data.players) but there is no response or anything , like the function is dead , no errors , the update is not done , just displaying the entry data

Here the input data:

```
{"id":1,"email":"d","password":"d","name":"d","price":5,"points":5,"fixture":"d","userid":1,
"players":
[{"id":2724,"firstname":"Lucas Digne","lastname":"Lucas Digne","position":"D","price":0,"rating":"7.3","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/2724.png","teamid":45,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592848,"points":2},{"id":19599,"firstname":"Emiliano Martínez","lastname":"Emiliano Martínez","position":"G","price":0,"rating":"6.6","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":5,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/19599.png","teamid":66,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592855,"points":11},{"id":2741,"firstname":"Mathew Ryan","lastname":"Mathew Ryan","position":"G","price":0,"rating":"5.0","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/2741.png","teamid":42,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592851,"points":-1},{"id":289,"firstname":"Andrew Robertson","lastname":"Andrew Robertson","position":"D","price":0,"rating":"7","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/289.png","teamid":40,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592850,"points":2},{"id":289,"firstname":"Andrew Robertson","lastname":"Andrew Robertson","position":"D","price":0,"rating":"7","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/289.png","teamid":40,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592850,"points":2},{"id":2726,"firstname":"Kurt Zouma","lastname":"Kurt Zouma","position":"D","price":0,"rating":"7.2","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":0,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/2726.png","teamid":49,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592851,"points":2},{"id":633,"firstname":"İlkay Gündoğan","lastname":"İlkay Gündoğan","position":"M","price":0,"rating":"8.3","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":1,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/633.png","teamid":50,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592852,"points":5},{"id":633,"firstname":"İlkay Gündoğan","lastname":"İlkay Gündoğan","position":"M","price":0,"rating":"8.3","appearences":1,"goals":0,"assists":1,"cleansheets":0,"redcards":0,"yellowcards":0,"image":"https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/633.png","teamid":50,"clubid":1,"fixtureid":592852,"points":5}]}
```

Here the node.js:

```
updatefixture:(data,callback)=>{

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));       
        for(var item of data.players){
          pool.query(
            'UPDATE squad SET appearences = 1, rating = ? goals = ? assists = ? , cleensheets = ?, redcards = ?, yellowcards = ? , points = ? WHERE id = ? AND fixtureid = ? ',
             [ 
             item.id,
             item.rating,
             item.goals,
             item.assists,
             item.cleansheets,
             item.redcards,
             item.yellowcards,
             item.points,
             item.id,
             item.fixtureid
             ],
    );
    }
    (error,result) => {  
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error);
      }
      return callback(null,result);
    }
     
  },
```

I just want a way to update all rows with the condition that made with where clause and make sure that the rows will be updated, any help for a beginner like me will be so appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just moved callback of `pool.query` function outside of the loop.

Try the following:

```js
updatefixture:(data,callback)=>{
     function addPlayer(item) {
          return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
              pool.query('UPDATE squad SET appearences = 1, rating = ? goals = ? assists = ? , cleensheets = ?, redcards = ?, yellowcards = ? , points = ? WHERE id = ? AND fixtureid = ? ',
               [ 
               item.id,
               item.rating,
               item.goals,
               item.assists,
               item.cleansheets,
               item.redcards,
               item.yellowcards,
               item.points,
               item.id,
               item.fixtureid
           ], (error, result) => {  
              if(error){
                reject(error);
              } else {
                accept(result);
              }
          });
        });
      }
        
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      Promise.all(data.players.map(addPlayer)).then((result)=>{
        console.log(result)
        callback(null, result)
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log('Error:', error)
        callback(error)
      })
 },
```

Comment: after the first loop it stops and return the result without updating all the rows

Comment: LearnDeep, I updated the code with conversion into Promise  - that way it easier to handle & understand the logic

Comment: why you deleted the return of callback? i need it for the controller , now the controller is not receiving it , but the logic is true , still missing the part of callback return